# Cpp program not working as expected

Tags: c++

Hi I have a simple cpp program to display the amount of money a customer need to pay when they purchasing a pizza. The code as follows. But somehow the amount is showing 0 instead of the correct answer. Someone please help, am really new to Cpp. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const int price = 20;

int main(){

    int radius = 0;
    int area = (3.14)* (radius);
    int amount;
    amount = (area) * (price);
    cout << " Enter the radius of the pizza u want \n";
    cin >> radius;
    cout << " Please pay amount" << amount << " at the cashier" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.ignore(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code.

Comment: Sorry all. Forgot to include the codes.

Comment: The amount is calculated before you change the radius.

Comment: `int area = (3.14)* (radius);` makes `area` 0 as `radius` is currently 0. Then, `amount = (area) * (price);` makes `amount` 0 as `area` is currently 0. Solution: Calculate everything after `cin >> radius`.

Comment: Is the confusion because you think that once you've had `int area = (3.14)* (radius)` the value of `area` changes dynamically if the value of `radius` changes? Because it doesn't do that. Once it's calculated it doesn't automatically chance unless you tell it to change.

Comment: ...and you declared area and amount as int, while they should be double. With int, your result will be truncated.

Comment: Contrary to maths, `area = 3.14 * radius` is not an equation that establishes a (faulty - that's not the area but half the circumference) relationship between an area and a radius but an action that changes the value of `area` into the current value of `3.14 * radius`. (And I would personally prefer to order a pizza with a specific *diameter*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting all of your valuables to 0 at the beginning. Try:

```
int radius:
```

at the beginning, this will create your variable but not give it a value, then after `cin >> radius;` you can do basically what you had before:

```
cin >> radius;
auto area   = radius*radius * 3.14;
auto amount = area * price;
```

Or you could just get rid of the `area` variable and just do:

```
cin >> radius;
auto amount = radius*radius * 3.14 * price;
```

---

Note also that the area of a circle is `pi*r*r`, not `pi*r`. Moreover, you shouldn't to the computation using `int`s. In above code `auto` will automatically be a floating-point number (`double` in this case, since `3.14` is a `double` literal).